# Autocomplete and Geonames: is it possible to retrieve city, state and country in separate input fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete, geonames

I am currently using a single INPUT field to trigger jQuery UI Autocomplete, which pulls data from Geonames.

```
$( "#city_state_country" ).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {
                featureClass: "P",
                style: "full",
                maxRows: 6,
                name_startsWith: request.term
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
                    return {
                        label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                        value: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 3,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        log( ui.item ?
            "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
            "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
    },
    open: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
    },
    close: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
    }
});
```

So if I begin to type "Bosto"

it provides me with

```
Boston, Massachusetts, United States
```

But I would like to have separate INPUT fields for city, state and country -- and each of them with autocomplete hooked up to Geonames returning only suggestions for city, state, country respectively.

So typing:

```
"Bost" in the city INPUT would provide "Boston".
"Massa" in the state INPUT would provide "Massachusetts".
"United St" in the state INPUT would provide "United States".
```

Is this possible?

I've experimented with changing `name_startsWith` to other [options](http://www.geonames.org/export/geonames-search.html) but didn't get what I expected.

Comment: Do you want to constrain State/Country? For example, should I not be able to type "Boston", "South Carolina", "United Kingdom"?

Comment: @andrew i don't want to constrain, i just wanted to offer cities, states and countries in separate fields, with autocomplete -- if someone entered what you suggested so be it

Comment: Realize this is very old, but FYI to others, I think this should be possible.  The jQuery example limits the featureClass to a value of "P" which limits the api to just [cities and villages](http://www.geonames.org/export/codes.html).  So you could leave that for your city input and then change it to "A" or something similar to get country/state for your other inputs.

Comment: To get country: http://api.geonames.org/search?maxRows=10&username=demo&featureClass=A&featureClass=A&featureCode=ADM1&country=US and to get state: http://api.geonames.org/search?username=demo&featureCode=ADM1&country=US

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html, you can't

Comment: thx - do you see where exactly they say it's not possible (which section of that page)?

Comment: Sorry, that was a vague answer. But it simply doesn't have a CONTAINS options. Even their full-text search doesn't really match your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using this URL - example : `api.geonames.org/postalCodeSearchJSON?placename_startsWith=dehi&country=LK&username=demo`

it will generate result for input that you gave.